# UIImageView doesn't animate when using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout

My image has the following constraints:

- leading = 0
- trailing = 0
- top = 75
- height = 250

I want my image to start from the right side of the screen and move to initial place where the constraints are set.

Here is my code:

```
imageLeadingConstraint.constant = 100
imageTrailingConstraint.constant = -100
imageTopConstraint.constant = 100
image.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    self.imageLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
    self.imageTrailingConstraint.constant = 0
    self.imageTopConstraint.constant = 75
    self.image.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The issue is that the image is moving to initial place, but not using an animation.
Is my code right ? How come the image just appears in the new position and not animating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `layoutIfNeeded` for imageView's superview.

```
self.image.superview.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: The user has tagged this question as swift based, your answer was in objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood you, but:
1) Change constraints (second time) outside of animation block. 
2) use self.image.superview?.layoutIfNeeded() instead